# Fail in "show desktop site" in safari

Tags: mobile, safari, desktop, user-agent

Fail in "show desktop site" in safari. I am developing a responsive site, but it is considered that users can select "show desktop site" on their mobile phones and in this case it should show the desktop view. However after several reloads on different iOS devices with safari, the "show desktop site" button stops working and continues to show the mobile version. I reviewed exhaustively and discovered that safari (and I suppose the rest of browsers) what they do is change the user agent to a non-mobile one when the user selects this option. However, after repeatedly reloading the "show desktop mode" button it stops changing the user agent, always being the user agent of ipad or iphone without making the change. Is there a known bug in safari that causes this? Anyone else has happened? Do you have any solution? Thank you

Comment: Show us by sharing that piece of code here. Its difficult to visualize your approach.